# Identify PCB components from picture

Tags: pcb-design, identification

The whole pcb represent a filtering and amplification stage for an incoming analog signal, before leading to and A/D stage.

reference: page 20

doi:10.1088/0967-3334/33/6/943

(I didn't want to post a reference that somebody might not have access to, but yes, it might be helpful)

Since I am trying to reproduce the project from a picture, I am interested in understanding what components where used.
My knowledge of the amplification and filtering stages is solid, but I am unsure on a few components, which I think to be safety/power management/interconnection related.

In the original source, the succesive A/D stage is left unspecified.

Here is the picture

[image]

I am trying to identify

1 and 2.

I think that

3 is the plug to the power line and

4 is the trimmer for a variable gain amplifier in the circuit.

I am fairly sure that

5 belong to a circuit splitting the incoming 12V power supply in two differential 5V (to power the amplifiers of 7 +/- with respect to a reference); and

6 is an on/off button

while

7 is the circuit implementing the actual function

If you could point me in the right direction, especially with 1 and 2, it would be an amazing aid.

Thank you in advance for you help,

Kind regards

Comment: With this information, there is no way to identify what the components are and what they do in the circuit. Yes, (1) and (3) are definitely connectors but no idea for what purpose and (2) might be a transformer of some sort for some purpose. (4) could be a rotary switch for unknown purpose, (5) are electrolytic capacitors for unknown purpose.

Comment: The picture is simply too bad to tell much about the components. It should be taken from above and in case of connectors from the side as well. Any written text on them should be included in the question.

Comment: Thank you Justme for pointing out that (3) should be a connector. A long as they are connectors, and I find a way to connect my instrumentation ( which I did) it doesn't matter if they are not the same. I will look into transformers and rotatory switches. Unfortunately, Lundin, I have posted the only picture of the circuit. The original poster presents Amplification&Filtering as novelties, and all the rest is left completely undescribed.

Comment: Simple solution - contact the author (e-mail address can be found in paper details). They are the ones who will know, and may be willing to share the information.

Comment: Did it. Sadly i didn't receive a reply...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. BNC connector  (signal out)
2. Isolation transformer
3. DIN connector (power in)
4. rotary selector switch (dipswitch) - probably gain select or something like that
5. SMT electrolytic aluminum capacitors
6. power ON/OFF rocker switch (most likely double pole)

The only one that is not obvious from the appearance is the isolation transformer (other modules are sold in similar packages) and the ID is from the line in the paper:

The other parts are the integrated circuits and other components that form the amplifier, as described in the paper.

> In addition (to the external medical power supply) "a transformer was
> used when the final output signal was sent to a data acquisition
> board."

Comment: How did you manage to see that 1) is a BNC?

Comment: @Lundin It looks exactly like the back end of a PCB-mount right-angle [BNC](https://i.imgur.com/PNXKEKh.png) (I've used enough of the d*** things) and it's connected to a data acquisition system.

Comment: I failed to understand that when they said "transformer" they meant a PCB component, and not an external element. About the connectors, I ended up finding the same connection methods, but now I can double check. Thank you, this is truly helpful

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Why BNC and not TNC? They have very similar dimensions.

Comment: @Lundin With a white plastic back like that, pretty rare. Do you have some reason to believe that it's a TNC and  that it matters in this case?

Comment: I have no reason to believe anything since the picture is so bad - could as well be a piece of lego for all I know. Though it didn't take me long to find a similar-looking TNC on google: https://p.globalsources.com/IMAGES/PDT/BIG/492/B1139307492.jpg.

Comment: @Lundin If OP is wanting to duplicate the circuit it doesn't matter much, especially if you like making your own cables. BW is kHz (sample rate 25kHz). Similarly, what I called a 'DIN connector' will be picked to match whatever comes on the COTS bipolar medical supply.